# Svnmapper is displaying a single line. Multiple branch lines expected

Tags: svn

I have been using svnmapper for some time now:
http://svnmapper.tigris.org/
Recently I switched to a different workstation, which involved me having to do a reinstall of svnmapper. Unfortunately, after importing my entire repository into the tool, all I get to see in the graph is a single red line instead of the jungle of branches that the repository really is.
Is anyone familiar with this? I haven't switched operating systems (currently using Windows 7 Ultimate x64) and as far as I'm concerned I configured everything accordingly to the previous situation in which the tool worked properly. Am I missing some graphical libraries perhaps?
My issue is **not** related to the one posted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147072/anyone-use-svnmapper-please-help-me

Comment: If anyone can point me to a freeware or open source alternative SVN graph tool I'd be just as happy as with a solution for my problem. But the tool *must* be capable of displaying merges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. Apparantly you need to point SVNMapper to the *trunk*-folder of the repository you would like to map and not to the root of your repository. (On a certain level it makes sense I guess, the root level *never* branches into anything; it'd explain the single red line.)

Upon revisiting your configuration in the realm cache however, it seems that SVNMapper automatically removes the *trunk*-folder from its URL notation. I'm not sure but I guess I must have blatantly copied the URL from there to my new workstation without taking a critical look at it.